# How can I resolve the " AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'unifontsubset' " error when using the FPDF library?

Tags: python, attributeerror, fpdf

I'm trying to use the FPDF library to generate a PDF file from a list of text files. However, I'm getting an AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'unifontsubset' error. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    from fpdf import FPDF
    import glob
    from pathlib import Path

    pdf = FPDF(orientation="P", unit="mm", format="A4")
    pdf.add_page()

    # List of file paths
    filepaths = glob.glob("Text+Files/*.txt")
    # Eracting a sigle file path from the list
    filepaths = filepaths[0]
    # Eracting the filename
    filename = Path(filepaths).stem
    pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt=filename, align='L')

    pdf.output("output.pdf")
```

I've already checked that the filepaths variable contains the correct file path, and the filename variable is extracted correctly(which is a type str).

The issue is probably related to txt=filename in pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt=filename, align='L')
I have tried to use f string in the following part of the code: txt=f"{filename}", however, the issue remains.

I have run the following code to upgrade fpdf: pip install --upgrade fpdf

However, the issue still remains.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using python 3.10 and Windows 10

*Full traceback is provided below for ready reference:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shibb\PythonProjects\App4.1_excercise_cats_dogs\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    pdf.cell(w=0, h=10, txt=filename, align='L')
  File "C:\Users\shibb\PythonProjects\App4.1_excercise_cats_dogs\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shibb\PythonProjects\App4.1_excercise_cats_dogs\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 685, in cell
    txt = self.normalize_text(txt)
  File "C:\Users\shibb\PythonProjects\App4.1_excercise_cats_dogs\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1099, in normalize_text
    if self.unifontsubset and isinstance(txt, str) and not PY3K:
AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'unifontsubset'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Apologies for the typos in the previous code block. 

from fpdf import FPDF
import glob
from pathlib import Path

pdf = FPDF(orientation="P", unit="mm", format="A4")
pdf.add_page()

# List of file paths
filepaths = glob.glob("Text+Files/*.txt")
# Extracting a single file path from the list
filepaths = filepaths[0]
# Extracting the filename
filename = Path(filepaths).stem
pdf.cell(w=50, h=20, txt=filename, align='L')

pdf.output("output.pdf")

Comment: please do not post edits in the comments section. Instead, _edit_ your post.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this line after pdf.add_page()
for example font name Arial and bold with size 8
pdf.set_font("Arial", "B",8)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the above line of pdf.cell as shown below:

pdf.set_font(family='Times',style='B',size=12)